# HTTP Status 500 - Filter execution threw an exception

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have implemented a Spring Security Application. After I logged into the application every time I got this error.

```
    type Exception report

message Filter execution threw an exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception
root cause

java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.changeSessionId(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:290)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.changeSessionId(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:290)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:202)
    org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:187)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy.applySessionFixation(ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy.java:55)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.AbstractSessionFixationProtectionStrategy.onAuthentication(AbstractSessionFixationProtectionStrategy.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy.onAuthentication(ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy.java:32)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy.onAuthentication(CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy.java:89)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:224)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:106)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.37 logs.
```

My Configuration classes as follows.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:config.properties")
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Value("#{'${AuthGeneral.permissions}'.split(',')}")
    private List<String> authGeneralPermissions;

    @Value("#{'${AuthAdmin.permissions}'.split(',')}")
    private List<String> authAdminPermissions;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("shehan").password("abc123").authorities("AuthUser");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("root123").authorities("AuthAdmin");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(authGeneralPermissions.get(0), authGeneralPermissions.get(1)).access("hasAnyAuthority('AuthUser') or hasAnyAuthority('AuthAdmin')")
                .antMatchers(authAdminPermissions.get(0)).access("hasAnyAuthority('AuthAdmin')")
                .and().formLogin();

    }

    @Autowired
    public MethodSecurityConfig getMethodSecurityConfig() {
        return new MethodSecurityConfig();
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    public List<String> getAuthAdminPermissions() {
        return authAdminPermissions;
    }

    public void setAuthAdminPermissions(List<String> authAdminPermissions) {
        this.authAdminPermissions = authAdminPermissions;
    }

    public List<String> getAuthGeneralPermissions() {
        return authGeneralPermissions;
    }

    public void setAuthGeneralPermissions(List<String> authGeneralPermissions) {
        this.authGeneralPermissions = authGeneralPermissions;
    }
}
```

WebInitializer class as follows

```
    @Configuration
public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer
{
    @Override
    public void onStartup( ServletContext container )
    {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register( SecurityConfiguration.class );
        //rootContext.setServletContext( container );

        container.addListener( new ContextLoaderListener( rootContext ) );

        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext =
                new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.register(AppConfig.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet( "dispatcher",
                new DispatcherServlet( dispatcherContext ) );
        dispatcher.addMapping( "/" );
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup( 1 );
    }
}
```

SecurityWebApplicationInitializer class as follows

```
    public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

AppConfig class as follows

```
    @Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.shehan.springsecurity")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{

}
```

pom.xml file as follows

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.websystique.springsecurity</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringSecurityMethodLevelSecurityAnnotationExample</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>SpringSecurityMethodLevelSecurityAnnotationExample</name>

    <properties>
        <springframework.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <springsecurity.version>4.1.0.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                        <warName>SpringSecurityMethodLevelSecurityAnnotationExample</warName>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <finalName>SpringSecurityMethodLevelSecurityAnnotationExample</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Don't post stack traces as images as those are unreadable. Post them as code.

Comment: Okay. I will update the question.

Comment: You have included a servlet 3.1 jar somewhere in your code on a servlet 3.0 container. That isn't going to work.

Comment: Can you post your pom file?

Comment: ok. I will add my pom.xml file as well

Answer (score 0):

can you add scope provided in three dependencies(javax.servlet, javax.servlet.jsp, jstl) and let me know if this worked for you.
More specifically for the following dependencies

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks Periklis. I have tried this solution. But it didn't work.

Comment: In the war that you are building can you see any jar javax.servlet*.jar?

Comment: No. It didn't contain any javax.servlet*.jar files